# Is there a way to search for youtube videos inside the terminal?

Tags: terminal, automation, gnome-terminal

I am wondering if there is a way for me to search for youtube videos inside of my terminal(POP OS), like the way the **Googler** package does. Basically, I want to type my keywords in my terminal and it will return for me a list of results from Youtube, then I pick one and it will open my selection in the browser.

I have tried with Googler, `googler -n 3 -w youtube.com my query`, but it just shows me no result no matter what my queries are. I also have tried the command `googler -V PyCon 2020` as mentioned in the official github page, but it seems like they have removed the functionality for the videos.

Comment: See [CLI utility to search and view/download YouTube videos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/495998/341192) and [Search and download audio-only from youtube](https://askubuntu.com/a/1326100/925128).

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research on GitHub, it has already been done using nodejs https://nodejs.org/en/

YouTube Search Google API for Node.js and Browser
https://github.com/LionRoar/youtube-api-v3-search

Comment: there are many other option, there is the youtube api (google) https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list